# Most popular search phrases in an elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is it possible to see which are the most popular searched phrases/words within a particular index in elasticsearch.

Can this be set up in kibana at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using Search Slow log - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html

You can set the slow log setting dynamically too. Once this is set you should see the logs in index_search_slowlog.log. Ingest these logs back to elasticsearch and visualize in kibana. You can create the dashboard from this data.

We use these slow logs to monitor slow queries, popular queries etc.